# ORA-01830: date format picture

Tags: sql, oracle

I need some help guys with this error >
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

```
INSERT INTO members_contributions 
            (contribution_type, 
             from_date, 
             to_date, 
             added_period_in_months, 
             member_amount, 
             mof_amount, 
             the_currency) 
VALUES      (2, 
             To_date('01/06/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 
             To_date('30/06/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 
             1, 
             55, 
             0, 
             'OMR')
```

Comment: Trying counting the number of characters you're passing as the first argument of the `TO_DATE()` calls and the number of characters in the second argument. Any ideas why you might be getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the time to the format mask

```
INSERT INTO members_contributions 
            (contribution_type, 
             from_date, 
             to_date, 
             added_period_in_months, 
             member_amount, 
             mof_amount, 
             the_currency) 
VALUES      (2, 
             To_date('01/06/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM'), 
             To_date('30/06/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM'), 
             1, 
             55, 
             0, 
             'OMR')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `to_date` function you have to mention the matching conversion string

```
To_date('01/06/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM') 
To_date('30/06/2016 12:00:00 AM', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MI:SS AM')
```